# Upgrading extension for Joomla 3 gives fatal php error

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I have a Joomla extension which is built for Joomla 1.5.
At the moment I'm upgrading the extension to work with Joomla 3.0

I updated old deprecated php functions in the new version of the extension.

The problem is when I activate the extension on my Joomla 3 site and I try to login into the backend, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in [my joomla folder]/libraries/vendor/joomla/application/src/AbstractApplication.php on line 126

Has anybody had this error before? If so, how can this be solved?

**Additional information:**

I've read the documentation of Joomla 1.5 & 3.
What I've seen during my research is that this error usually occurs when you try to load a Joomla 1.5 template into a Joomla 3 website. But in this situation it's totally different. The problem resides in the extension. But I can't figure out which function is causing the issue. It could be that the old Joomla 1.5 code is still in the extension.  Too bad Joomla does not have a way of searching through deprecated Joomla functions.

When I add a debug_backtrace() I get all arrays printed on the screen, but after that I get:

> Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "[joomla dir]/libraries/vendor/joomla/application/src/AbstractApplication.php" at line 128.

I placed the debug_backtrace() before the return in the get method.
(So I don't get to see a complete array list).

The last array I get to see before the error:

```
[5] => Array
    (
        [file] => /[joomla dir]/index.php
        [line] => 46
        [function] => getApplication
        [class] => Joomla\CMS\Factory
        [type] => ::
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => site
            )
    )
```

Comment: I googled that and found an issue on the Joomla tracker that indicates that you may stiI'll have code that is no longer available in J3.  Can you explain what you have tried and what research you have done? Also a stack trace would probably find where the null is being called, since that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: Hi @Elin, thank you for your response. I've added more information in my question.

Comment: Joomla has logging that you can turn on and it will log deprecated functions for you. Also you should make sure that you have error reporting configured to development and debugging turned on in the global configuration (you can edit the file directly).  You don't mention what kind of extension this is, is it a plugin? Also there is a whole separate stackexchange for Joomla [joomla.se] that probably 20 people could answer you question on.